# Add Reference to PluralizationServices in .NET Standard Class Library

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

I am moving methods from my old .NET framework 4.5 class library to a new .NET Standard 2.0 class library. However, I am having problem with one method that uses System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.

```
public static string ValueWithUnit(double value, string unit)
{
    PluralizationService pluralizationService = PluralizationService.CreateService(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"));
    string valuePart = value.ToString("0.##");
    string unitPart = value > 1 ? pluralizationService.Pluralize(unit) : unit;

    return $"{valuePart} {unitPart}";
}
```

How do I add PluralizationServices in .NET Standard 2.0 class library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the library Humanizer.Core that I can use for pluralization in .NET Standard. I just installed the package using Nuget package manager and updated my code like so:

```
string unitPart = value > 1 ? unit.Pluralize(inputIsKnownToBeSingular: false) : unit;
```